# How to set counter with predefined variable in java

Tags: java

I need to set counter with variable to start number as variable. e.g my variable "COUNT" could be any value between 1 to 12 and followed by remaining numbers. Consider this

if COUNT = 3 then my series of number should go like below

3 (Assigned run time variable)

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

11

12

1

2

Many thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in single for loop like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int COUNT = 3;
    for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
        if (i + COUNT > 12) {
            System.out.println(i + COUNT - 12);
        } else {
            System.out.println(i + COUNT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Binod Karunanayake

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this - you can play with the modulus operator, `%` or you can take advantage of the fact that a for-loop can increment more than one variable at a time. So you use one variable to control the loop count, and another for the print value:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=3;
        for (int i=0; i<12; i++, x++) {
            if (x>12) {
                x=1;
            }
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
...
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
1
2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int countStart = 3;

for(int count = countStart; count < 13; count++){
    System.out.println(count);
}

for(int count = 1; count < countStart; count++){
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

The code starts from `COUNT` which is written here as `countStart`, and keeps printing until it reaches 12.

From here, a new loop runs from 1 to `countStart`, printing all the values

With only one loop

```
int count=3;
    for(int i=count;i<count+13;i++){
        if(i<13)
        System.out.println(i);
        else if(i>13){
            System.out.println(i-13);
        }
    }
}
```

Here your count start from 3
it will iterate the loop through 13+count to print all value 
after that it will check if the i vale lessthan 13 then it will print the i value else it print i-13 from 1,2 ... upto cont-1

Comment: Since the user appears to be new to SO, it would be loads more helpful if you included an explanation for your answer as well

Comment: thanks Aseem Salim .  But Is there a way it can be done in a single loop?